# WIndows Driver to retrieve address of newly added RAM

Tags: wdk

If i add a new RAM ro my DIMM slot, how can I find the physical address of the same in the windows kernel

Answer (score 1):

Not. RAM has no identity. It's like water. If you add one liter to one liter, you have two liter of water but you can't point out which is which.

Comment: Agreed. But still there should be way to get the added addresses at the driver, kernel level. I'm sure Windows maintains a list of addresses as part of the newly added RAM.

Comment: Nope. There's one pool, and you can't determine which is new and which is old. And unless you stored it yourself, you can't determine how much there was. Even if you did, you can't distinguish adding 2GB from swapping a 2GB DIMM with a 4GB.